# Sort individual components of a list in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list containing 1000 3-dimensional lists.

```
[[ 0.17  0.045  0.01]
[ 0.28  0.10 0.19]
[ 0.31  0.19  0.09]
..., 
[ 0.36  0.42  0.38]
[ 0.62  0.02  0.03]
[ 0.32  0.12  0.26]]
```

Is there a quick way to sort individual components of a list rather than the laborious way of iterating through the list? eg in the above case, if I had just 6 lists (inside the outer list), I want to get 3 lists, each containing 6 elements sorted in ascending order .

```
[ 0.17, 0.28, 0.31, 0.32, 0.36, 0.62 ]
[ 0.02, 0.045, 0.10, 0.12, 0.19, 0.42 ]
[ 0.01, 0.03, 0.09, 0.19, 0.26, 0.38 ]
```

Another small question, how can I print all 1000 lists. If there are just 100 lists, all of them are printed if I use `print` statement but for 1000 lists, all 1000 are not printed if I use `print` (as you can above, `...` is printed after printing 3 lists) . I can print all of them if I use

```
for i in list_coll: print i
```

but isn't there a more direct way ?

Comment: Do you have a list of lists or is that actually a 2d numpy array?  I ask because there aren't any commas between terms, and that's how a numpy array would look if you printed it.

Comment: I am sorry, it was a 2D numpy array and not a list of lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a 2d numpy array, you can use the `sort` method on arrays, and specify `axis=0`:

```
>>> d
array([[ 0.17 ,  0.045,  0.01 ],
       [ 0.28 ,  0.1  ,  0.19 ],
       [ 0.31 ,  0.19 ,  0.09 ],
       [ 0.36 ,  0.42 ,  0.38 ],
       [ 0.62 ,  0.02 ,  0.03 ],
       [ 0.32 ,  0.12 ,  0.26 ]])
>>> d2 = d.copy()
>>> d2.sort(axis=0)
>>> d2
array([[ 0.17 ,  0.02 ,  0.01 ],
       [ 0.28 ,  0.045,  0.03 ],
       [ 0.31 ,  0.1  ,  0.09 ],
       [ 0.32 ,  0.12 ,  0.19 ],
       [ 0.36 ,  0.19 ,  0.26 ],
       [ 0.62 ,  0.42 ,  0.38 ]])
```

And then you can transpose this if you want to work with the rows and not the columns:

```
>>> d2.T
array([[ 0.17 ,  0.28 ,  0.31 ,  0.32 ,  0.36 ,  0.62 ],
       [ 0.02 ,  0.045,  0.1  ,  0.12 ,  0.19 ,  0.42 ],
       [ 0.01 ,  0.03 ,  0.09 ,  0.19 ,  0.26 ,  0.38 ]])
>>> for row in d2.T:
...     print(row)
...     
[ 0.17  0.28  0.31  0.32  0.36  0.62]
[ 0.02   0.045  0.1    0.12   0.19   0.42 ]
[ 0.01  0.03  0.09  0.19  0.26  0.38]
```

Et cetera.

Comment: list did the work but certainly, thanks for this useful piece of information, obviously this also works

Answer (score 3):

If you have a list of lists you can get the sorted lists you can use `zip` in a list comprehension:

```
[sorted(entry) for entry in zip(*list_coll)]
```

This will work regardless of how many items are in each sublist as long as they all have the same number of items. So for example:

```
>>> list_coll = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [-1, -2, -3], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> [sorted(entry) for entry in zip(*list_coll)]
[[-1, 1, 4, 7], [-2, 2, 5, 8], [-3, 3, 6, 9]]
>>> list_coll = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [-1, -2, -3, -4], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
>>> [sorted(entry) for entry in zip(*list_coll)]
[[-1, 1, 5, 9], [-2, 2, 6, 10], [-3, 3, 7, 11], [-4, 4, 8, 12]]
```

If you have one sublist with fewer items, then this actually still works but only sorts up to the number of items in the smallest sublist. For example:

```
>>> list_coll = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [-1, -2, -3], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13]]
>>> [sorted(entry) for entry in zip(*list_coll)]
[[-1, 1, 5, 9], [-2, 2, 6, 10], [-3, 3, 7, 11]]
```